# Boot problem with fiber NIC, CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot

Strange problem here.  I'm upgrading to a new desktop (HP Z440) with CentOS 7.  The install was done on a CAT5 network with the built in NIC.  Everything appeared to work fine.

The final environment is on a fiber network, so a PCI fiber card is installed.  lspci description (on the old system):

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 54)
Subsystem: Allied Telesis AT-2701FX
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 32 (6000ns min, 6000ns max)
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=32]
Region 1: Memory at fa010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Expansion ROM at f0000000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcnet32
Kernel modules: pcnet32code here
```

That appeared to be fine as well - as long as no cable is connected.
Once the network cable is connected to the fiber NIC, it won't boot.  It gets as far as the kernel select screen, then the screen goes blank for a bit.  On rare occasion, I get the message:

```
Uncompression Error
System Halted
```

and then it just hangs.  Most of the time it simply kicks it back to bios and an apparently never ending loop of boot failures.

The card works fine on the old system (HP 8200 Elite, CentOS 6.2). And two different cards (same manufacturer, different model) have been tried with the same behavior.

If the network cable is plugged in once the system is booted, nothing happens.  Haven't actually tried configuring it there yet.  For some reason the network management tool (system-config-network) isn't installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I solved it, but not good news.

I booted the new system with the card installed, but no cable plugged in and looked at the lspci output.  The big difference is that there is no "kernel driver" or "kernel modules" section in the output for the card.

modprobe tells me that pcnet32 is not available, and looking through /lib/modules/ that appears to be the case.

A bit more googling reveals that the pcnet32 driver has been dropped in RHEL 7 (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Migration_Planning_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Migration_Planning_Guide-en-US.pdf pg 70)

So I guess I'm SOL unless/until I find a new network card :(